# Correct usage of ImageDataGenerator flow function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-augmentation

I am trying to use data augmentation for a regression model in Keras. Therefore I want to use the `ImageDataGenerator` class from Keras. Nearly all tutorials I can find on that task have a classification approach and thus use the method `flow_from_directory`. But with a regression task, this doesn't work.

Then I stumbled across the `flow` method, but sadly there are no good examples for using it. The only thing I can find is that people are using it to output augmented data directly to the hard drive. What I want to do is (like with `flow_from_directory`) use the generator and put it in the `fit_generator` function. But the results I got are not very good and I am not sure if it's the augmented data or if I am using the `flow` method wrong. Here is what I did:

```
# Load the data (images will be model input, labels will be model output)
# NOTE:    
# images.shape = (45, 256, 256, 1)
# labels.shape = (45, 2)
images, labels = load_dataset(base_path=os.getcwd(),
                          type=dataset_type.FrontalPrimary)

# split into training and test data
    split = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.10, random_state=42)
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = split

# make data fit model
trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2], 1))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX .shape[0], testX .shape[1], testX .shape[2], 1))

# create generator for each, training and test
data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=10,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    validation_split=0.15)

train_generator = data_gen.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=1)
test_generator = data_gen.flow(testX, testY, batch_size=1)

# train model
model = cnn.get_model()
model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=64, epochs=500)

# make predictions on the testing data
preds = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=10)
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed something else. If I setup `data_gen` like the following

```
data_gen = ImageDataGenerator()
```

or if the data isn't normalized already

```
data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)
```

The results are far from what I tested without the data augmentation, even though `ImageDataGenerator` should not have transformed any image. How is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

It is very likely that your images are not already normalized (i.e. the pixel values are in the range [0,255]). So you need to normalize them and one simple way of doing that is to use `rescale` argument:

```
data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255., ...)
```

---

A few other points:

- You are doing training with augmented data which is totally fine. But make sure you also want to do the testing with augmented data as well. Otherwise, for test phase you need to create a new instance of `ImageDataGenerator` which does not do any augmentation on test images:

  ```
  test_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)
  test_generator = test_data_gen.flow(testX, testY)
  ```
- If you have 40 training images (%90 of whole data) and set the `batch_size=1`, then there would 40 batches per epoch. So you need to set the `steps_per_epoch` accordingly to 40 (or better than that, set it to `trainX.shape[0]`). Although, if you had more images then batch size of 1 would not be efficient in terms of using all the resources available (i.e. GPU/CPU). The same thing applies to `steps` argument of `predict_generator`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will take a look at your suggestions as soon as possible

Comment: So the images were already in the range of (0,1). I did the normalization in `load_dataset`. I've updated the step for training and testing. But I don't understand the other point. You said that I should do testing with augmented data too, but didn't I already do that? Unfortunately my predictions weren't getting better with updated step size

Comment: @Codey No I did not meant that you **should** do augmentation in test phase. I said you are **doing it currently** because you are using the same `ImageDataGenerator` instance, i.e. `data_gen`, as used for training (i.e. `test_generator = data_gen.flow(testX, testY, batch_size=1)`). So I just said make sure that you did it **intentionally**. I am out of ideas. Please edit your question and add the model's definition; maybe there is an error there.